# querying an int value and pulling a date range

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select all orders from this date 2013-12-13. The information is in integer value. The query will run but is not giving me any info.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(modified)
FROM orders
WHERE (modified BETWEEN '2013-12-13 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-14 00:00:00')
```

Comment: what does your table look like? what data do you have? Consider using http://sqlfiddle.com to create an example?

Comment: If `modified` is an `int`, as `FROM_UNIXTIME` suggests... you can't really compare that to date strings, can you? (Well, one can, but that would to some things you don't want or expect).

Comment: "The information is in integer value" - what does this mean? What information?

Comment: The date is converted to int value is what I mean

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(modified)
FROM orders
WHERE modified BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-12-13 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-12-14 00:00:00')
```

Comment: This is a valid query, but its still returning 0 rows.